# Passing data from child to parent in dynamic component

Tags: angular

I have been following the tutorial on dynamic components in Angular and have a solution working but I cannot seem to find how to pass data from the child to the parent.

In this live example ([StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yu5lxk?file=src/app/ad-banner.component.ts)), I'd like to be able to click the button in the child component (`HeroProfileComponent`) and receive it in the parent component (`AdBannerComponent`).

How can I accomplish this and is it a sign of an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add another input - a function - that can be called on click by child - similar to how you've passed `data` value in on your stackblitz example.

```
(<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
// similarly
(<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).clickEvent = this.clicked;

clicked($event) {
   console.log('Parent', $event)
}
```

And then in the AdComponent:

```
@Input() data;
@Input() clickEvent: Function;

onClick() {
  this.clickEvent(this.data)
}
```

This will call the clicked method in the parent and allow you to pass data to parent

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yu5lxk-emqbwl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fad-banner.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use the eventemitter you should solve your problem, I am attaching an image that can give you an idea

[image]